# C# - Easier way to repeat code after an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

Is there any simple way to repeat code in a try/catch block after an exception occurs without using method recursion or goto statements? I'm calling a web service and then pushing that data to a SQL database using Entity Framework, and if the second step fails after the first one succeeds, I'd prefer a simpler or cleaner way to re-try that step rather than recursing the same method (the two steps are in separate methods for this very purpose) or using a goto statement.

Comment: Loop until it succeeds? Every recursion can be written as a loop.

Comment: Your webservice methods should be atomic.

Comment: Oh great, now I have to figure out what an atomic method is. I've seen the term dropped here and there, but my experience with the word is that it should cause the app to melt down :) which is counter-productive. Seems to mean something else entirely, so I guess that goes on the "figure out what that means" list for now.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, if you fall into the `catch` block then it is advisable to do cleanup and logging rather climbing back with `goto` or `recursion`.

Now to answer your question;

Keep your both step within a `Transaction` block and follow an approach of try enter, which in otherwise trying to execute a block of code until you succeed or for a limited number of times.

```
//Code outline only idea and not production quality code.

    var timesTried=0
    while(timesTried<5) //here I try trying to execute 5 times
    {
     using(var tran = new TransactionScope())
     {
        CallMethodA();
        CallMethodB();
        tran.Complete();
        timesTried=6
     }
      timesTried++;
    }
```

Comment: Only answer so far to mention he should be doing something with the exception rather than just ignoring it and trying again.

Comment: this doesn't catch any exceptions, and even if it did, it would repeat the `CallMethodA()`. The OP does not want to repeat the first method if an error occurs during the second one.

Comment: Instead of setting `TimesTried` to `6`, I would just use a `break;` statement. I would use a `for` loop for doing things five times, the initialization `var timesTried = 0` and increment `timesTried++` could be moved to the `for`, for clarity. But those are simple details, of course.

Comment: I always log the situation whenever I hit a catch block. Cleanup is usually minimal because the objects I use are managed by a calling function or the parent class and so are disposed of after the method returns.

Having said that, I'm going to educate myself some more on the Transaction classes. The only thing this approach lacks for this current problem is that it would repeat the first call as well as the second, and changing it to do them separately would make this more complex than the other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Your usecase isn't very clear but it sounds like you need a simple state-machine:

```
var state = 0;
while(state < 2)
{
    try
    {
        if(state == 0)
        {
            CallWebService();
            state = 1;
        }
        if(state == 1)
        {
            PushData();
            state = 2;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // do something useful (log, decrement retry count, etc.)
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this answer. The only thing that would be annoying (to me, anyway) is that, since I don't want unlimited retries, I'd have to add a counter so that it would exit after a specified number of retries.

Comment: @Ant yes, you can add a counter or you can even have separate counters for web and db actions. It's trivial work.

Answer (score 2):

If you only wanted to repeat it once, you could use a delegate:

Something like this:

```
bool failedOnce = false;

Action myAction = delegate
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
        failedOnce = true;
    }
};

myAction();

// try again
if (failedOnce)
{
    myAction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a
    do {
     }
    while(x== ??)

loop. Also you can complete any other actions you may have missed if an exception is caused by using the finally statement

Answer (score 1):

Consider a wrapper method which could call the method of operation. Here is a rough sample of how it would be...

```
private void Wrapper()
{
    try
    {
        Method();
    }
    catch
    {
        Method();
    }
}

private void Method()
{
    try
    {
        // Operations
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Importent never suppress an exception just repeat you can also build some delay in repeat but not sppressing please.

```
private static void DoQuery(DbContext dbContext, int throwCounter)
{
  try
  {
    Query();    
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (throwCounter< 10)
    {
      DoQuery(dbContext, throwCounter++);
    }
    else
    {
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

If you wana to do it very proffesional check this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680905(v=pandp.50).aspx

If you are using EF6 than it support retry strategy.

Comment: We're still using EF4 (although we're in the process of upgrading from VS2010/.NET4). Thank you for the link, though. I do log all exceptions, too, and am trying to ensure that I only retry when the exception conditions are likely to clear up with a pause.

Comment: Yes very good you can build a sleep or await in the catch if you want it async delay and I hope this will solve your problem.